# How to see the repositores you have created in Github via command line?

Tags: command-line, repository, git, github

How can I see the repositores you have created in Github via command line?

Comment: See [How to retrieve the list of all github repositories of a person? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713596/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a HTTP GET request to GitHub's REST API to query a list of repositories owned by a given user. I will use `wget` for the request, which should come preinstalled on Ubuntu. An alternative tool could be e.g. `curl`.

The response is a quite big JSON object, therefore I decided to use `jshon` (install it with `sudo apt install jshon`) as JSON parser to only extract the repository names. You could also just look at the full response or use any other parsing methods you like. If it's just for human readers and you don't care much about formatting, simply piping it through `grep full_name` should already suffice.

---

So, let's start with the command. To get a list of my public GitHub repos (the user name is "ByteCommander", obviously), I would run this:

```
wget -qO- 'https://api.github.com/users/ByteCommander/repos' | jshon -a -e 'full_name' -u
```

You should get some output similar to those lines (just a few more...):

```
ByteCommander/AdventOfCode
ByteCommander/ByteCommander.github.io
ByteCommander/ChatExchange6
ByteCommander/dynamodb-local
```

---

The command above can be broken down into the HTTP request made by `wget`, which gets its response outputted on STDOUT and piped into the JSON parser which extracts the relevant information.

```
wget -qO- 'https://api.github.com/users/ByteCommander/repos'
```

This obviously sends a request to the given URL. Replace `ByteCommander` with your respective GitHub user name. The `-qO-` are options which modify how `wget` outputs the response. It's short for `-q` (quiet, no progress/status output) and `-O -` (output file is STDOUT). Read more about that in `man wget`.

```
jshon -a -e 'full_name' -u
```

This makes the `jshon` parser read JSON data from STDIN (where `wget`'s output gets piped) and parses it according to the specified options. `-a` applies the following operation on all elements of the response array: `-e 'full_name'`, which extracts the `"full_name"` property of the objects it is applied to. `-u` finally just removes the quotes around the extracted string values. Read more about it in `man jshon`.

You can find a detailed explanation of the GitHub v3 REST API and especially the list-user-repositories endpoint and its JSON response format in [their official documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories).